# opencart shared order, one cart - multiple customers

Tags: opencart, e-commerce

I'm looking for a solution to share an order on opencart. Basically what I need is if I'm in an office and I add to cart a product, to have an url, which I share with my colleagues.

My colleagues will be able to add in the same cart the products they want, While on my screen i see what they added.

Once I see everybody added to the cart, I'll continue placing the order as 1 customer.

Is this possible? Is there any extension for this on opencart (2.3.x)

Thanks.

Comment: i've never heard of an extension like that but it sounds easy enough to create.  if it's something you'd like to hire out i might be interested.  are you a programmer or just looking for commercial support?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like something you might want

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=21677

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me give a more clear example. I have a home delivery restaurant. There are many people in the same office which are looking to buy. Instead of talking one with the other, they should be able to share a special url and all of them to add in the same cart. After which the order will be send.

Comment: Oh,I believe opencart has that by default if you are registered (e.g. if you log in with your account add some items to the cart and than logout these things will still be there untill you empty the cart)